# What software can I use to complememt our useless company task planning and time tracker tool?

Tags: tools, pm-software, process

We have Remedy-based software that is used for task planning and time tracking. No real project management features are supported, but we need to use it because our budgets are calculated using the software.

I would like to introduce an effective set of tools to improve our project management process while keeping it aligned with the "master" planning/tracking software. An idea would be to use something different (e.g. Basecamp or similar) and then implement some integration layer to the DB.

How do I start? Any advice?

Comment: Actually Basecamp, and most of them, have API's designed to be easilly integrated with any software.

Comment: What is PM and sw?

Comment: @Kieran: 'project management' and 'software', respectively.

Comment: @davpi, I will suggest that you change your question to something similar to. How to I introduce a PM software in my company?, you might get more replies this way.  BTW. This is a great question.

Comment: @Geo, maybe you can help here.  What _is_ the question? How to replace a useless task planning and time tracker tool?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your question.  I think Davpi is not looking to replace his current tool, just to complement it with a real PM tool.  At least that was my understanding. He even mentions integration in his post.  my two cents.  Have a nice day.

Comment: Exactly, change the tool is unachievable, because the whole company administration relies on this. It is not project management oriented, but we are forced to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.  I'm not familiar with Remedy but I truly hope you end up with one integrated solution and not two separate ones.

To meet the needs of two constituents I wouldn't take the silent/side project development approach.  I would try to work with in-house Remedy stakeholders and explain the project management needs that could be addressed by an extending the Remedy-based solution.  While an under-the-radar project will proceed faster it won't be inclusive of people that will probably be key to acceptance and adoption.

It's been my experience that going it alone (creating a Remedy interface without input from internal owners) might not result in adoption because the very people you need to go forward may feel disenfranchised.  At a minimum, it will take a while to get them on board with the idea.  Better to include them in the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

As I said before, this is a good question.  I struggle through this in every company that contracts me.  It does not matter the size of the company this will always exist.  To address your question, the short answer is that you need to use politics. Yes, I know you were not looking for that.

1. The first thing you need to do is silently get all the **main pain points**. Try to avoid emotions in the situation.  Remember no one cares that you spent your weekend getting a report ready, but they do care that the same report will take only 20 minutes, and it will be at the fingertips of executives.
2. You need to plan your tactic and strategy. No tool will make it, if you don't have a process in mind or in paper.  Tools are useless if you don't have a process that go with it.
3. After you gave enough thought to your plan and strategy, then get buy-in.  Tell a few co-workers about your plan over lunch and see their re-action.  Be appreciative of feedback but remember to support your plan (that is a fine balance).  Incorporate any feedback that will get the support of a leader in your team. Then go for your boss.

The rest is to enjoy the view, after your company is working more effectively.

Hope this works. Geo

Comment: Thanks Geo for the great feedback. Obviously it's not a matter of which tool to adopt, and indeed your suggestions confirm more or less my nighlty thoughts. I think/hope I have the right team to silently develop some prototype in extra time.

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to have a good time tracker for your group to be more productive and organize. I suggest you look for a time tracker that tracks your worker's hours real time. You can [try reading about time doctor](http://www.timedoctor.com/biz3.0/why-100k-developers-are-dead/), this is a more enhanced time tracker. It tracks your employees' hours real time plus it also provides task management so that you will know what task are worked on a specific time. In doing so, this could provide you a more efficient and productive team members that can increase the company's outcome.

Comment: Thanks daniey for pointing out time doctor, and in general the blog itself is evry valuable.

Answer (score 1):

[Disclaimer: I am one of the developers working on time cockpit]

If you are looking for something flexible/adjustable you can take a look at [www.timecockpit.com](http://www.timecockpit.com). It features a dynamic data model (adjustable lists and forms), allows scripting using python, has good excel integration (import/export),
a great calendar and activity tracker (makes it easier for employees to track their time). Feel free to contact me if I can help you with it in any way!

Answer (score 0):

[Vertabase](http://www.vertabase.com) has been used in conjunction with Remedy at large organizations to provide project management and time-tracking functionality, as well as project status reporting.

(Disclosure, I work for Vertabase.)

Answer (score 0):

We have a time tracker that allows you to track time to various projects within your organization and then roll everything up so you can see where your team is spending time.  You can also place limits and budgets on your team for specific projects.  You can see it here https://hubstaff.com - let me know if you have any questions.